# AWS malformed policy error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to set an AWS group policy via the AWS CLI like so:

```
aws iam put-group-policy --group-name my-group --policy-name \
    s3-full-access --policy-document /tmp/policy.json
```

This is the content of /tmp/policy.json:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
A client error (MalformedPolicyDocument) occurred when calling the PutGroupPolicy operation: The policy is not in the valid JSON format.
```

I do not know how to proceed, the error is too unspecific. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Solved this riddle!

There **has** to be a `file://` prefix in front of the policy file name:

```
aws iam put-group-policy --group-name my-group --policy-name s3-full-access --policy-document file:///tmp/policy.json
```

The original error message is very misleading, as you get the same message if you provide a filename that *does not exist at all*.

So it is **not** the **syntax of the policy** in the file but the fact that the **CLI does not see the file at all**, that causes the error.

Comment: Note that a prefix of `file://` and an absolute path that starts with `/` might mean you need `file:///mypath/myfile.json` (three forward slashes instead of two).

Comment: geez. I saw the file in a tutorial I was following but I took it out because I figured it was a Windows thing

Comment: for a relative path (current directory): `file://./config/file.json`

Comment: kinda dumb, the CLI should use `-f` option like normal people

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue on window 10 and this help me.

```
**file** : followed by **two Forward slash** like         :"file://"
**Path on window 10** : followed by **Backward slash** like 
:"c:\Users\Anand\Desktop\anand-jan19.json"

C:\Users\Anand>aws iam create-policy --policy-name anand-jan19 --policy-document file://c:\Users\Anand\Desktop\anand-jan19.json
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "anand-jan19",
        "PolicyId": "EQWEQBV33ewrwYCRCS",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::56433378:policy/anand-jan19",
        "Path": "/",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v1",
        "AttachmentCount": 0,
        "PermissionsBoundaryUsageCount": 0,
        "IsAttachable": true,
        "CreateDate": "2019-02-10T04:03:32Z",
        "UpdateDate": "2019-02-10T04:03:32Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PS command: Example 1.

aws iam create-role --role-name vmimport --assume-role-policy-document file:///policy/trust-policy.json

****Actual path******: C:\policy\trust-policy.json
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

PS command: Example 2.

aws iam put-role-policy --role-name vmimport --policy-name vmimport --policy-document file:///policy/role-policy.json

****Actual path******: C:\policy\role-policy.json
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: What is your question exactly?