# MalformedPolicyDocument when calling the CreatePolicy operation - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

I am trying to configure `ALB Ingress Controller on Amazon EKS` and following steps outlined in the document `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html`

however, when i run

```
aws iam create-policy \
    --policy-name ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy \
    --policy-document https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.4/docs/examples/iam-policy.json
```

I am getting the following error 
`An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy`

any help in fixing this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Worked just fine for me

Comment: did not work for me, however, i downloaded the file and pointed to it using file protocol.

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Hi, I am using Mac

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For anyone who might see a similar issue, I downloaded the json and point to the file using the `file` protocol.

```
aws iam create-policy \
    --policy-name ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy \
    --policy-document file:///iam-policy.json
```

I found the answer here [AWS malformed policy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026348/aws-malformed-policy-error)

Comment: With my case I need to use: `file://path-to-file` instead of `file:path-to-file`. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that the example has one too many `/`. Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Just put quotes `'` on json call:

```
aws iam create-policy \
        --policy-name ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy \
        --policy-document 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.4/docs/examples/iam-policy.json'
```

Comment: using aws-cli/2.7.35 I do see the `(MalformedPolicyDocument)` error with this snippet using `https://`. Has it changed?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `file://<file-name.json>` instead of `file:///<file-name.json>` for --policy-document parameter and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

```
aws iam create-policy --policy-name ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy --policy-document file://"iam-policy.json"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).